What is the best way to compile Python code to WASI?
I have a Python script that reads a file from a path. For what I know, compiling the script to WebAssembly will require to make use of WASI, as the script needs to access system calls to read the file.
What is the best way to compile a Python script to a WASI module?
Maybe I'm confused with the differences between WebAssembly modules and WASI modules, but for what I studied those are different and require different tools to compile.
